# CSS Background : Adding left padding via using repeat-x with single element

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-repeat

I try to create heading like this...

> Title --------------------

This line with a custom image background

**HTML :**

```
<h2>Title</h2>
```

**CSS :**

```
h2 {background:url('line.png') repeat-x 15px 10px;}
```

**Result :**

[image]

Live : http://jsfiddle.net/5G2aq/

---

I try to repeat this image with X-axis and add some padding into the left.

But it doesnt work, `15px` doenst work... or what ?

PS :Try to do with a single element `<h2>`, not `:after` or full-long image

Any trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this, use `:after` pseudo with `content: "";` and be sure you use `display: block;`, now we use `position: absolute;` and assign `position: relative;` to the container element. Last but not the least we use `overflow: hidden;` so that we don't get dirty scroll.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5G2aq/1/)

```
h2 {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h2:after {
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 60px;
    background:url(http://oi39.tinypic.com/m7t8xw.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```

---

Coming to your solution, you are using `repeat-x`, so you won't see the `background-position` changing on the `x` axis as the image is repeating, if you want to go for this approach, you shouldn't repeat.

---

Even better approach

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/5G2aq/2/) OR [**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/5G2aq/3/) (Using your image)

```
<div><span>Hello</span></div>

div {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

div span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    background: #fff;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

The above way will be title `width` independent, I would've chosen this way

> Note: You can replace `div` with `h2`

Comment: So I have to use CSS3 `:after` ?

Comment: @l2aelba btw I doubt your title is fixed length?

Comment: btw , i really know this solution (using `:after`) , But thanks anyway :D

Comment: @l2aelba I provided an alternate solution :)

Comment: ha :D I already know this solution also :P , but thanks agian. I seeking for CSS hack some I dont know before :D

Comment: So, I will use `:after`, I give up about older browsers :P

Comment: @l2aelba yea after is fine too :)

Comment: @l2aelba: `:after` isn't new to CSS3. It's supported by IE8 and later.